# Css classname not applied to react component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, react-boilerplate

I appreciate your time and help. I spent hours trying to figure this out can't seem to get to the bottom of it.

I have this react component:

```
import styles from './style.scss';

class ButtonComponent extends React.Component { 
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.bunny}>
        hello world
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and scss file:

```
.bunny {
  display: block;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-bottom:55px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

When I load up my html, the div has no classname when I expect it to be `<div class="bunny">`

When I put the class name in the react component literally like this:

```
<div className="bunny">
```

then I can see the className in the browser.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: How are you using the `css-loader` inside webpack?

Comment: I'm using the react-boiler-plate project, this is what I have in the webpack-base.babel.js

`{
        // Preprocess our own .css files
        // This is the place to add your own loaders (e.g. sass/less etc.)
        // for a list of loaders, see https://webpack.js.org/loaders/#styling
        test: /\.(s*)css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },`

Not sure if this helps, can you be more specific?

Comment: Importing css or sass files does not actually import any javascript object that you can use inside your js files as css files do not export anything. It just  tells your module bundler (webpack) to include the css file in your bundle if it uses your component somewhere. Just import the file with `import './style.scss'` and then use your classes as strings: `<div className="bunny">`. Of course your html file will need to link the css file too. It's more like tellling webpack: "Hey webpack, this component uses classes from this sass file so include it in my bundle."

Comment: Hi Trixn, this is not desired as I do not want to hard code classnames in js files. I have seen this working before but I'm not sure what I have configured wrong myself.

Comment: @trixn that is simply not true.

Comment: @calpang You do not appear to be using the `modules` property offered by webpack's `css-loader` in order to used modularized css where you can import the style sheet and reference the classes like object properties

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need to guarantee it's defined with: `console.log(styles)`
Im' not sure you import style.scss correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import your scss like...
`import './styles.scss';`

Webpack will take care of bundling your styles so you can add the className as a string on your component.

```
<div className="bunny">Hello World</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

there was a similar problem. It turned out that I named the style file not news.module.scss, but news.modules.scss. After renaming "modules" to "module" and then importing the file, className started working

Answer (score 0):

What fixed this for me was to change the name of my scss file from `style.scss` to `style.module.scss`

Answer (score 0):

For me it's because I use commonjs's `require` to load an es module.